# Parâmetro ViewModel sendo passada como null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estou tentando validar meu formulário de login, mas a função "ModelState.IsValid" não está realizando a validação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a imagem acima, ao executar a Action, o parâmetro "EfetuarLoginViewModel" está sendo passado como "null". Segue abaixo o conteúdo da minha ViewModel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using HolisticWeb.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HolisticWeb.ViewModel
{
    public class EfetuarLoginViewModel
    {
        public EfetuarLoginViewModel()
        {
            Login = String.Empty;
            Senha = String.Empty;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Nome de Usuário")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe seu Login")]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe sua Senha")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Senha { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está sua url? ela está uma estrutura parecida com essa ***http://localhost:50339/Dashboard/ViewModel?Login="MeuLogIn"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no construtor, onde você coloca um comportamento que, além de não ser necessário, atrapalha o validador.

```
    public EfetuarLoginViewModel()
    {
        Login = String.Empty;
        Senha = String.Empty;
    }
```

`[Required]` avalia corretamente se a String é, mas não vazia. O correto seria você apenas retirar o construtor e testar de novo.

Ainda, se você realmente quiser usar `String.Empty`, você vai precisar usar outro atributo que converte `String.Empty` para nulo:

```
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome de Usuário")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe seu Login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe sua Senha")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Senha { get; set; }
```